# Install oracle-instantclient-basic in ubuntu container

Tags: python, oracle, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I am trying to install oracle-instantclient-basic in ubuntu image using rpm.

I am Using Macbook pro with M1.

When I am trying to build the image for Linux the Dockerfile works fine with the command:

```
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t security-docker-stat.mydartifactory.swinfra.net/buisness_monitoring:latest .
```

But when I am trying to do the same thing for my environment on my mac using this command:

```
docker build --no-cache -t security-docker-stat.mydartifactory.swinfra.net/buisness_monitoring:latest_OSX .
```

the process exit with an error on the step:

```
RUN alien -i /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

The Dockerfile I am using is:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get install -yq alien

# Install oracle client and utils


RUN curl -o /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm "https://mydartifactory.swinfra.net/artifactory/security-generic-stat/oracle/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm"

RUN alien -i /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm

RUN apt-get install -y libaio1

ENV ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
ENV PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin

RUN apt-get install -y less wget vim

# Install Python

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y
RUN apt-get update

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=Etc/UTC apt-get -y install tzdata

RUN apt-get install -y python3.9
RUN rm /usr/bin/python3
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
RUN apt-get install -y python3.9-distutils
RUN python3.9 get-pip.py

RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools

# Install Python packages
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/

RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

# Cleanup
RUN rm -f /tmp/*.rpm


USER stat

ADD bin /home/stat/bin

ENTRYPOINT ["/home/stat/bin/main.py"]
```

And the error that I get is:

```
 =\> \[internal\] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                       0.0s

 =\> =\> transferring dockerfile: 1.43kB                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s

 =\> \[internal\] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s

 =\> =\> transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s

 =\> \[internal\] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                                                                                                            3.2s

 =\> \[auth\] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                              0.0s

 =\> \[internal\] load build context                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s

 =\> =\> transferring context: 183B                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s

 =\> CACHED \[ 1/24\] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:450e066588f42ebe1551f3b1a535034b6aa46cd936fe7f2c6b0d72997ec61dbd                                                                             0.0s

 =\> \[ 2/24\] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                                                                                             3.8s

 =\> \[ 3/24\] RUN apt-get install -yq alien                                                                                                                                                                 22.7s

 =\> \[ 4/24\] RUN curl -o /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm "https://mydartifactory.swinfra.net/artifactory/security-generic-stat/oracle/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.  7.9s 

 =\> ERROR \[ 5/24\] RUN alien -i /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                 7.3s 

\------                                                                                                                                                                                                          

 \> \[ 5/24\] RUN alien -i /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm:                                                                                                                            

\#9 0.300 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY                                                                           

\#9 0.307 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY                                                                           

\#9 0.314 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY                                                                           

\#9 0.321 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY                                                                           

\#9 0.328 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY

\#9 0.335 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY

\#9 0.341 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY

\#9 0.348 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY

\#9 0.355 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY

\#9 0.362 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY

\#9 0.368 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY

\#9 0.375 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY

\#9 0.382 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY

\#9 0.389 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY

\#9 0.396 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY

\#9 0.403 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY

\#9 0.405 Warning: Skipping conversion of scripts in package oracle-instantclient-basic: postinst postrm

\#9 0.405 Warning: Use the --scripts parameter to include the scripts.

\#9 7.106 warning: /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY

\#9 7.191 /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm is for architecture amd64 ; the package cannot be built on this system

\------

executor failed running \[/bin/sh -c alien -i /tmp/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.6.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm\]: exit code: 2
```

Please can someone help me with this?

thanks a lot :)

Comment: Are you sure building correctly the docker image for x86 on Apple M1? Some hints that may help here: https://erica.works/docker-on-mac-m1/

Comment: It's should be OK because it's not my first time  using Docker on my mac, but thanks I will look into the link you send and see if there is the result in there :)

Comment: not to avoid your question, but what are you going to use the client for? Because it's quite possible you can do what you want WITHOUT installing the client at all